# Custom validators in WTForms using Flask

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms

I need to make a custom validator in WTForms where the input is to be: *number*:*number* - e.g. 2:1

```
match1 = StringField('Russia-Saudi Arabia', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

So, my question is - how to create such validator?

I've looked upon the documentation at http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html, but was not very helpful (for me) in this case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can write a custom validator within a form by writing a `validate_{field_name}` method. If it raises a `ValidationError`, the form will not be valid and will display the error.

For your specific case, here's a solution using regex. It finds the match for the string, and then uses a bit of splitting to get back the scores. After validating the form you can access the scores by `form.score1`, `form.score2`.

```
import re
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm

class MatchForm(FlaskForm):
    match1 = StringField("Russia-Saudi Arabia", validators=[DataRequired()])

    def validate_match1(form, field):
        if not re.search(r"^[0-9]+:[0-9]+$", field.data):
            raise ValidationError("Invalid input syntax")

        s1, s2 = form.data.split(":")
        form.score1 = int(s1)
        form.score2 = int(s2)
```

Comment: @janmpeterka Should be `def validate_match1(self, form, field)` or you can make the method static with `@staticmethod`

Comment: Also `from wtforms import ValidationError` seems to be missed. Please consider editing this answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, validators

# Define a custom validator function
def custom_validator(form, field):
    if len(field.data) < 5:
        raise validators.ValidationError('Input must be at least 5 characters long')

# Define a Flask form with a StringField and a custom validator
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    my_field = StringField('My Field', validators=[validators.InputRequired(), custom_validator])
```