# How to make apply an extra custom validator to 2 fields in a flask form?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, customvalidator

I've seen this method in the link below for creating custom validators and would like to use the same style, but would like to apply the validator 2 fields and require either field 1 or field 2 to not be empty. I could use an alternative method but this seemed the neatest if possible to adapt for this job.
[Custom validators in WTForms using Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327174/custom-validators-in-wtforms-using-flask)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to write a function that checks both fields for an input.

```
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError
from wtforms.compat import string_types

def validate_one_required(form, field):
    if (not form.field_1.data or \
            isinstance(form.field_1.data, string_types) and \
            not form.field_1.data.strip()) and \
        (not form.field_2.data or \
            isinstance(form.field_1.data, string_types) and \
            not form.field_1.data.strip()):
        raise ValidationError('One field is required.')
```

A more advanced variant is to write a class that validates both inputs.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError
from wtforms.compat import string_types

class OneRequired(object):
    def __init__(self, fieldname, message=None):
        self.fieldname = fieldname
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        try:
            other = form[self.fieldname]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValidationError(field.gettext("Invalid field name '%s'.") % self.fieldname)

        if (not field.data or isinstance(field.data, string_types) and not field.data.strip()) \
            and (not other.data or isinstance(other.data, string_types) and not other.data.strip()):

            d = {
                'other_label': hasattr(other, 'label') and other.label.text or self.fieldname,
                'other_name': self.fieldname
            }
            message = self.message
            if message is None:
                message = field.gettext('This field or %(other_name)s is required.')

            raise ValidationError(message % d)

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    field_1 = StringField('Field 1',
        validators=[
            OneRequired('field_2')
        ]
    )
    field_2 = StringField('Field 2',
        validators=[
            OneRequired('field_1')
        ]
    )
```

Depending on the requirements you have, the choice is yours.